# Stored data taken from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with my code. My objective is to fetch some data from database and update the database again.

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {

    if ($phpgsb->doLookup($row['origin']) === true) {           
        echo var_dump($phpgsb->doLookup($row['origin'])). " - ". $row['origin'];

mysql_connect("localhost", "ali", "password");
mysql_query("UPDATE `mydatabase`.`dns_soa` SET active='N' WHERE origin='".$row['origin']."'");

echo "<br>";
}
}
```

the output of `echo var_dump($phpgsb->doLookup($row['origin'])). " - ". $row['origin'];` is

```
bool(true) - hello.com.
```

which is weird because if I remove mysql connect code

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "ali", "password");
mysql_query("UPDATE `mydatabase`.`dns_soa` SET active='N' WHERE origin='".$row['origin']."'");
```

the correct output from database will be shown:

```
bool(true) - hello.com.
bool(true) - jool.com.
bool(true) - kool.com.
```

Se everytime I ran this code only hello.com. record will be updated in database. This is wrong. How can I get all 3 records to be updated using my UPDATE query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need to call a connect everytime inside the loop, MySQL will already re-use the last link. Connect before the first query and procede

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take this line:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "ali", "password");
```

and put it out (before) of the while loop. You don't need to connect again and again to the db.

Comment: I need to make the connection again because I have 2 user with 2 different database. They both don't have access to each other database. I ended up granted full privileges to user ali to both of my database so only 1 connection is needed. This automatically solved my problem. Credits to both of you for giving me the database privilege idea. Thanks again to Damien Pirsy and AurelioDeRosa :)